# LU factorization of a simple matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have the matrix 
$$A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&1\\1&-1&1\\1&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It is invertible so it has an LU-factorization (Am I right about that?)

I tried to solve it, I first reached that the upper matrix is equal to
$$U=P(2,3)E_1A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&1\\0&2&0 \\0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where
$$E_1= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\1&1&0 \\1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And $P(2,3)$ is the matrix that switches the 2nd row with the $3$rd row.

But I continued as I usually do, the matrix $L$ usually turns out to be $L=[P(2,3)E_1]^{-1}$, but this wasn't a lower matrix !!

I got that
 $$L= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\-1&0&1 \\-1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I checked my calculations $3$ times I don't think I have calculation mistakes...

Can anyone help please by giving a correct method and tell me what I did wrong in the method I used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $A$ is invertible, then it admits an LU factorization if and only if all its leading principal minors are non-zero.

So $A$ doesn't have an LU factorization since a leading principal minor is zero, which means that,
$$D_2= 
\bigg|
\begin{matrix}
-1&1\\1&-1
\end{matrix}
\bigg| =0
$$

But matrix $A$ has a PLU decomposition

Answer (score 2):

You have to perform Gaussian elimination without row swaps.
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&1\\
1&-1&1\\
1&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&1\\
1&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_1\gets -R_1
\\[6px] &\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
0&0&2\\
0&2&0
\end{pmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets R_2-R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3-R_1 \end{aligned}
\end{align}
No, the matrix does not admit an $LU$ decomposition, with $L$ lower triangular and $U$ upper triangular.

If you swap rows to begin with,
\begin{align}
P(2,3)A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&1\\
1&1&-1\\
1&-1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
1&1&-1\\
1&-1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_1\gets -R_1
\\[6px] &\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2\\
\end{pmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets R_2-R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3-R_1 \end{aligned}
\\[6px] &\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets \tfrac{1}{2}R_2 \\ R_3&\gets \tfrac{1}{2}R_3 \end{aligned}
\end{align}
Thus you get
$$
U=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
L=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
A=P(2,3)LU
$$
If you don't do pivot reduction, the idea is essentially the same.

Comment: Can you please explain your idea a bit more? Why $A$ doesn't have an LU factorization? I didn't quite get it, maybe because I don't know the conditions for a matrix to have the LU factorization...

Comment: @FareedAF If it had, you'd find it by performing Gaussian elimination with no row swap.

Comment: Isn't it true that if the matrix is invertible then it has an LU factorization? This matrix is invertible and it doesn't have an LU factorization why?

Comment: @FareedAF No. Consider the matrix $P(2,3)$, for instance. However, the definition of LU decomposition may vary; what's yours?

Comment: it is to write the matrix as a product of 2 matrices L and U, where L is a lower triangular matrix and U is an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: @FareedAF OK. Not every matrix can and your matrix $A$ is an example, but also any $P(i,j)$.

Comment: What is the other condition other than the 'invertibility' of the matrix A is required?

Comment: @FareedAF See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218770/62967

Answer (score 1):

Since you are swapping the second and third rows, you must multiply by the corresponding elemenetary matrix: 
$$A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&1\\1&-1&1\\1&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\-1&1&0\\-1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&1\\0&2&0\\0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}=PLU.$$
See [WA answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-1,1,1%7D,%7B1,-1,1%7D,%7B1,1,-1%7D%7D%20LU%20decomposition).

Answer (score 0):

You know that $L$ will be a lower triangular matrix with ones in the diagional. Now look at the pivots in $U$, and conclude all columns (and rows) contain pivots. Now you go back to your $A$ matrix, and divide the columns by the diagonal pivot. In your first column, $-1$ is on the diagonal, thus you divide the entire column by $-1$. In your second column, $-1$ is on the diagional, thus all the entries below the diagonal (in this case only the third row) will be divided by $-1$. The same applies for the third, getting

$ L=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  ,$ does this make sense?

Comment: $A \ne LU$ for the the $L$ you suggested

Comment: Ah, I guess that's because $U$ is different. I like egregs explanation.