# Solving System of equations and L-U decomposition of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition

I just read about the L-U decomposition method to decompose matrices to upper and lower triangular ones. And I saw some examples of solving systems of equations using this method.

My question: with what conditions can we safely use this method to solve the system of equations?
For example should the coefficient matrix be necessarily a square matrix? In other words when can one write the matrix $A$ as $LU$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a Square Matrix have an LU Decomposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218770/when-does-a-square-matrix-have-an-lu-decomposition)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of LU decomposition is to solve a system of equations without going through the route of matrix inversion. If the coefficient matrix is not square, then the system of equations is either under-constrained or over-constrained depending on the number of equations available (i.e, number of rows) and number of unknowns (i.e, number of columns).
Also, for a non-square coefficient matrix, you can't decompose it into two triangular matrices.

Comment: Oh good point. I hadn't notice that.

Comment: What about tridiagonal matrices. can we decompose it using LU method?